# For loop vs If statement using conditional variable

Tags: multithreading, go, asynchronous, thread-safety

I'm extending the `sync.Pool` type by limiting the amount of objects that can reside outside the pool. To achieve this I'm using `sync.Cond` to wait until a call to `Pool.Put` is made. To prevent users from creating a zero value of my struct, I'm not exporting it and defined an interface too.

My question is: when checking the condition to `Cond.Wait` the `sync` package advises to `Wait` in a loop. But considering my current implementation I think that using an `if` suffices. Given the code below and assuming that nothing wil be modified, can I change the `for` loop around `Cond.Wait` to a simple `if`?

```golang
type pool struct {
    pool sync.Pool
    n    int
    max  int
    lock sync.Mutex
    cond *sync.Cond
}

type Pool interface {
    Get() any
    Put(x any)
}

func NewPool(n int, f func() any) Pool {
    p := &pool{
        pool: sync.Pool{
            New: f,
        },
        max: n,
    }
    p.cond = sync.NewCond(&p.lock)
    return p
}

func (p *pool) Get() any {
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()
    // change to if?
    for p.n >= p.max {
        p.cond.Wait()
    }
    p.n++
    return p.pool.Get()
}

func (p *pool) Put(x any) {
    p.pool.Put(x)
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()
    if p.n > 0 {
        p.n--
    }
    if p.n < p.max {
        p.cond.Signal()
    }
}
```

Comment: `Wait` just releastes the mutex lock, and suspends the routine where `Wait` is called. When `Wait` returns, there's absolutely no way you can be certain that `p.n >= p.max` unless you check it again. You may think that `Wait` will return because `Put` was called, but `Wait` can return because another routine called `Get`.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Why would `Wait` return when `Get` is called?

Comment: My bad, you're using `Signal`, using a conditional, though, would quickly become problematic if you switch over to `Signal`. this example is all in all rather simplistic, and real-world code more often than not does merit your `Wait` condition to be re-evaluated. The recommended pattern (and more defensive approach) therefore is to use a loop to ensure the condition is checked once `Wait` re-acquires the lock. You could technically use an `if` _at the moment_, but with the same number of lines, your code is, in many ways, better with the `for`